# Why would you wrap FileOutputStream with a DataOutputStream?

Tags: java

A DataOutputStream can wrap a FileOutputStream, but I don't understand why it has been used here.

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(args[0]);
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);
dos.writeByte('j');
```

The last line does the same as `fos.write('j');` What does DataOutputStream add in this situation? i.e. why is there?

Comment: *"can any one explain it?"* Can you copy/paste code samples (at least so the code is compilable)?  Can you use your shift key at the start of sentences?

Comment: Did you do a `question.toLowerCase()` before posting here? Please use proper cases in your words and code.

Comment: Your code is incorrect. You have mistaken capitalization and the wrong constructor argument on the second line. Don't be sloppy since the Java compiler will not be forgiving. We as programmers are forced to value precision and accuracy and to look down on carelessness. Please correct these errors.

Comment: Read the JavaDocs for [FileOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) and [DataOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html). You'll find all your answers there.

Comment: Took the liberty of re-writing the question to make sense. There were some many errors, it wasn't possible to give a good answer.

Comment: @Peter: and edited it some more so that the DataOutputStream constructor now has the correct parameter. It just doesn't make sense for it to pass itself as its own parameter.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Streams in Java are defined according to the [Decorator design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

This means that you can compose a specific functionality (implemented inside a specific stream class) with another stream. This allows you to customize what you can do with streams. In your specific example

- a `FileOutputStream` is a *concrete component* which provides the functionality to write to a stream that is mapped to a File
- a `DataOutputStream` is a *concrete decorator* that, attached to another decorator or component, is able to extend the functionality by giving you a way to write primitives onto the stream, without caring about what there is in the underlying chain of decoration